# Creating loops and filters in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have an app that is based on **AngularJS**. Also, I make quite a heavy use of **lodash**.

There are functionalities that both libraries cover, like **looping** with `_.each` and `angular.forEach` basically doing the same thing. Another example would be **filters**: I can filter my objects in the controller with lodash, or include a filter from angular inside the template.

What are **best practises** when choosing the library that does these jobs? If I would use lodash consequently for all of those functionality, are there any limitations or pitfalls I have to consider?

Answer (score 1):

Advantage of using filters of angular is that you can use them in your views without any plumbing i.e. `<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:"name"/>`

For other mechanisms such as looping and stuff I believe the best is to use what you feel most comfortable with. Only thing to consider is that if you see that adding a new library doesn't bring you any more power other than adding a new dependency; it is a good idea to get rid of that dependency too.

But using libraries such as `lodash` and `underscore` is a good idea as it includes very powerful functions that will be convenient eventually in a big project.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them (Angular and lodash) solve your problem - they iterate over the given array. The only difference, imho, is performance. Take a look at [Angular's forEach](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L217) and [from lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.10.1/lodash.src.js#L6605). Of course both of them need more deep investigation but seems that lodash's version is a bit quicker. Also you should consider it only if performance is important for you as the difference won't be big.

About adding lodash - if the "main" framework (Angular in your case) solves all problems that you need (e.g. iterating over array with good perfomance) - there's no need to add one more library. Adding lots of libraries (when each of them is used in a few cases) could make your project very complex.

So if you decided to add lodash to your project - use it as much as possible - as @cubbuk wrote - it's a very powerful library.